# Get on sale dates for the variations of a WooCommerce variable product

Tags: php, wordpress, date, woocommerce, product-variations

Is there any way to get `on_sale_from` and `on_sale_to` dates for WooCommerce variable products in an array using PHP?

The highlighted red boxes in this screenshot:

[image: the red parts in this picture]

Comment: Try to be more explicit… What do you want to do with it? Where you are going to use that? So edit your question to make that clarifications please.

Comment: i want to use them in a function to create a countdown timer . all i need is to get those dates..for simple products is easy to get them...but for variable products they return null

Comment: The problem is that in a vraible product, there are multiple product variations, so you can have multiple on_sale_from and on_sale_to dates… how are you going to manage that?

Comment: let's imagine they all have the same start and end date. is there any way to get those dates ?

Comment: i looped through the variations. i can reach all the data about those variations including: width, height, on sale price, regular price but still i can't reach those dates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following to get the variations `on_sale_from` and `on_sale_to` dates for a variable product:

```
$sale_dates = array(); // Initializing

if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
    $variation_ids = $product->get_visible_children();
    foreach( $variation_ids as $variation_id ) {
        $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );

        if ( $variation->is_on_sale() ) {
            $date_on_sale_from = $variation->get_date_on_sale_from();
            $date_on_sale_to   = $variation->get_date_on_sale_to();
            
            if( ! empty($date_on_sale_from) || ! empty($date_on_sale_to) ) {
                $sale_dates[$variation_id] = array(
                    'from' => $date_on_sale_from,
                    'to'   => $date_on_sale_to,
                );
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Array row output
    print_r($sale_dates);
}
```