# How to extend the "variation.php" template file with available or custom data in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, product

I want to customize the **variation.php** file in WooCommerce

Path : */themes/theme-child/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variation.php*

I want to remove the part that shows the price and show my custom data instead:

```js
<div class="woocommerce-variation-price">{{{ data.variation.price_html }}}</div>
```

Now i want to put the regular price, the sale price, the on sale from and on sale to date of each variable. That is, when each variable is selected, display the desired data.

I did this easily for the simple product, but I don't know how to get the regular price, sale price, etc.. of the variable product, so that when you go to each variable, the data of that variable will be displayed.

In my search for an answer I found:

- [Display woocommerce variable product price](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44675192/11987538)
- [Get on sale dates for the variations of a WooCommerce variable product](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63279363/11987538)

Unfortunately this doesn't fully answer my question.

---

For example: I want to show the regular price and sale price of each variable, that's mean:

- Variable 1 : regular price = $20 | sale price = $15
- Variable 2 : regular price = $30 | sale price = $20
- Variable 3 : regular price = $40 | sale price = $25

If the user selects variable 1, it will show the regular price of $20 and the sale price of $15. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What should be mentioned first of all is that the **variation.php** template file **is slightly different from the other WooCommerce template files**, this because it is a javascript-based template.

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.template

The code below is taken from the [/single-product/add-to-cart/variation.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variation.php) template file (line 16-20 @version 2.5.0)

```js
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-variation-template">
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-description">{{{ data.variation.variation_description }}}</div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-price">{{{ data.variation.price_html }}}</div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">{{{ data.variation.availability_html }}}</div>
</script>
```

The intention is to extend this file in the same syntax or to apply the same methods!

---

The `get_available_variation()` function from /includes/class-wc-product-variable.php (line 346-394 @version 3.0.0) plays an important role in it:

```php
/**
 * Returns an array of data for a variation. Used in the add to cart form.
 *
 * @since  2.4.0
 * @param  WC_Product $variation Variation product object or ID.
 * @return array|bool
 */
public function get_available_variation( $variation ) {
    if ( is_numeric( $variation ) ) {
        $variation = wc_get_product( $variation );
    }
    if ( ! $variation instanceof WC_Product_Variation ) {
        return false;
    }
    // See if prices should be shown for each variation after selection.
    $show_variation_price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_variation_price', $variation->get_price() === '' || $this->get_variation_sale_price( 'min' ) !== $this->get_variation_sale_price( 'max' ) || $this->get_variation_regular_price( 'min' ) !== $this->get_variation_regular_price( 'max' ), $this, $variation );

    return apply_filters(
        'woocommerce_available_variation',
        array(
            'attributes'            => $variation->get_variation_attributes(),
            'availability_html'     => wc_get_stock_html( $variation ),
            'backorders_allowed'    => $variation->backorders_allowed(),
            'dimensions'            => $variation->get_dimensions( false ),
            'dimensions_html'       => wc_format_dimensions( $variation->get_dimensions( false ) ),
            'display_price'         => wc_get_price_to_display( $variation ),
            'display_regular_price' => wc_get_price_to_display( $variation, array( 'price' => $variation->get_regular_price() ) ),
            'image'                 => wc_get_product_attachment_props( $variation->get_image_id() ),
            'image_id'              => $variation->get_image_id(),
            'is_downloadable'       => $variation->is_downloadable(),
            'is_in_stock'           => $variation->is_in_stock(),
            'is_purchasable'        => $variation->is_purchasable(),
            'is_sold_individually'  => $variation->is_sold_individually() ? 'yes' : 'no',
            'is_virtual'            => $variation->is_virtual(),
            'max_qty'               => 0 < $variation->get_max_purchase_quantity() ? $variation->get_max_purchase_quantity() : '',
            'min_qty'               => $variation->get_min_purchase_quantity(),
            'price_html'            => $show_variation_price ? '<span class="price">' . $variation->get_price_html() . '</span>' : '',
            'sku'                   => $variation->get_sku(),
            'variation_description' => wc_format_content( $variation->get_description() ),
            'variation_id'          => $variation->get_id(),
            'variation_is_active'   => $variation->variation_is_active(),
            'variation_is_visible'  => $variation->variation_is_visible(),
            'weight'                => $variation->get_weight(),
            'weight_html'           => wc_format_weight( $variation->get_weight() ),
        ),
        $this,
        $variation
    );
}
```

The `$variation_data` from that function is passed/converted to the **variation.php** template file, by default `variation_description`, `price_html` and `availability_html` are used in the **variation.php** template file.

However, in the above function you see that by default much more data is passed such as `attributes`, `backorders_allowed`, etc..

For example, if you change the code in the  **variation.php** template file (follow the appropriate method to overwrite template files) to:

```js
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-variation-template">
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-description">{{{ data.variation.variation_description }}}</div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-price">{{{ data.variation.price_html }}}</div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">{{{ data.variation.availability_html }}}</div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-regular-price">{{{ data.variation.display_regular_price }}}</div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-display-price">{{{ data.variation.display_price }}}</div>
</script>
```

You will see that automatically the `display_price` and the `display_regular_price` are now also displayed. This is because it was already available by default.

---

**But what if you want to display data that is not available by default?**

For that you can use the `woocommerce_available_variation` filter hook and then edit the **variation.php** template file:

**Step 1)** code goes in **functions.php** file of the active child theme (or active theme)

```php
function filter_woocommerce_available_variation( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    // Add extra data
    $variation_data['my_custom_data'] = __( 'My custom data', 'woocommerce' );

    return $variation_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'filter_woocommerce_available_variation', 10, 3 );
```

**Step 2)** add the following line in the **variation.php** template file:

```js
<div class="woocommerce-variation-my-custom-data">{{{ data.variation.my_custom_data }}}</div>
```

The result is that our custom data now is displayed, only this is the same for each variation. To avoid this, we can use can use the extra arguments that are passed to the `woocommerce_available_variation` filter hook, namely `$product` and `$variation`.

---

Let's say we want to use `date_on_sale_from` and `date_on_sale_to` for each variation, if set. Then you get:

**Step 1)** code goes in **functions.php** file of the active child theme (or active theme)

```php
function filter_woocommerce_available_variation( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    // Getters: when NOT empty, get data in the desired format
    $date_on_sale_from = ! empty( $variation->get_date_on_sale_from() ) ? $variation->get_date_on_sale_from()->format( 'j F Y' ) : '';
    $date_on_sale_to = ! empty( $variation->get_date_on_sale_to() ) ? $variation->get_date_on_sale_to()->format( 'j F Y' ) : '';

    // Push
    $variation_data['woocommerce_available_variation'] = array(
        'is_on_sale' => $variation->is_on_sale(),
        'from'       => $date_on_sale_from,
        'to'         => $date_on_sale_to
    );

    return $variation_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'filter_woocommerce_available_variation', 10, 3 );
```

What as a result will add the following to the `$variation_data`:

```php
[woocommerce_available_variation] => Array
    (
        [is_on_sale] => 1
        [from] => 12 August 2022
        [to] => 31 March 2024
    )
```

**Step 2)** add/change the following lines in the **variation.php** template file:

```js
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-variation-template">
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-description">{{{ data.variation.variation_description }}}</div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-price">{{{ data.variation.price_html }}}</div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">{{{ data.variation.availability_html }}}</div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-date-on-sale-from">{{{ data.variation.woocommerce_available_variation.from }}}</div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-date-on-sale-to">{{{ data.variation.woocommerce_available_variation.to }}}</div>
</script>
```

In short, what is used in the filter hook as naming, to extend `$variation_data` should also be used in the template file.